# BLE Rssi analysis

Tags: c#, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an app which uses Rssi, and I need to know whether is person moving or not based on a data from few scans. Let's say I've got few arrays with information about each BLE device found, one array for each scan. My idea is to compare data of last 2 scans and if it's difference in Rssi between the same points is minimal (because Rssi value can change even if one isn't moving) then we could say that person is standing still. So I was wondering will this approach work and if there is any formula to minimize the error in this calculations. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a smartphone app ? If so you can use nRF Connect on Android to see a graph of the RSSI signals of BLE devices around (advertising).

I tried it with a BLE device at 10cm from my smartphone and the signal was oscillating from -56dBm to -50dBm, so I think it will be hard to achieve a great precision. You'll have to filter the signal a lot. I don't know if those changes are due to the emitter or the receiver, since the distance doesn't change.

Here is the trial I just did : 
[image]

Comment: Yeah, i'm doing this on Xamarin forms for IOS and Android. I'm able to see BLE devices nearby and their RSSI and connect to them. I've tested it and RSSI value changes like on 2-3dBm if i don't change the position of a phone. So I guess, I'll be able to determine wether the person is standing or moving. But the question is how to perform those calculations in minimum amount of time. Thanks for your help though!